# Unable to Upload Huge Files/Datasets on Google Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataset, google-colaboratory, data-processing

I am uploading a TSV file for processing on GColab, the file is 4GB and the upload process is not getting completed from a very long time (hours). Any pointers here are of great help. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlLFQ.png) to check upload process details

Answer (score 1):

It can be your internet connection. The import function for Google Colab is better useful when you `upload small .py files`. For huge files, I'd suggest you use Google Drive and upload it there in your account then simply move or copy it to your Google Colab instance:

**1. Copy the file you want to use:**

`%cp "path/to/the file/file_name.extension" "path/to/your/google-colab-instance"`

Google colab instance is usually like this - `/contents/`

Similarly,

**2. Move the file you want to use:**

`%mv "path/to/the file/file_name.extension" "path/to/your/google-colab-instance"`

The first "" would be the path to where you uploaded the .csv file in your drive.
Hope this helps. Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi Jimit! In my case, I should first download the DB from a URL, then upload it to google colab. Is there a way to download the file directly to google drive?

Comment: @ZeynabRostami You can do that using Google's cloud engine API, since G suite services are based on their backend. You can learn more on that before implementing it.